# How to reload a html element by resizing page without refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like to reload a html element (a canvas) when I resize my page, without refesh the entire page. Is that possible ?

Thank's !

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what your html element you need to reload is, but it should be possible.

Here's an example of a **jQuery** function that will check when the page is resized.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      var win = $(this); //this = window
      if (win.height() >= 820) { /* ... */ }
      if (win.width() >= 1280) { /* ... */ }
});
```

**Javascript example:**

```
window.onresize = function() {
    if (window.innerHeight >= 820) { /* ... */ }
    if (window.innerWidth <= 1280) {  /* ... */ }
}
```

And inside the `if` statement of your desired window height or width, you could call the function to reload your canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an event listener

```
window.onresize = function(){
   var oldcanv = document.getElementById('canvas');
   document.removeChild(oldcanv)

   var canv = document.createElement('canvas');
   canv.id = 'canvas';
   document.body.appendChild(canv);
}
```